# "Salted rim glass" vs "rimmed salt glass"

Tags: adjectives, word-order

Which one is correct;

> The drink is served in a salted rim glass

or

> The drink is served in a rimmed salt glass

Comment: In your second example, the glass is made of salt and has a rim. I think you mean the glass has a salted rim. :-)

Comment: _Saucer of salt, please; I prefer to do it myself._

Comment: Neither. The drink is served in a *salt-rimmed* glass.

Comment: @KristinaLopez Well, more realistically a "salt glass" might mean a glass intended to contain salt, like a "wine glass" is not made out of frozen wine, but rather is intended to hold wine. But in any case, I'm pretty sure that's not what he's trying to say.

Comment: @Jay, touché! I didn't think of it that way. lol!

Answer (score 2):

[StoneyB](https://ell.stackexchange.com/users/32/stoneyb) is spot-on, as per usual, though he's being modest and answering via comment.

For the sake of posterity, I'll supply my long-form answer (which happens to agree with his).

That is, **the best way to say this is:**

> **The drink is served in a salt-rimmed glass.**

In this case, you've come across a very specialized use of “rim” as a verb that's specific to the context of preparing (alcoholic) drinks. It basically means “To coat the upper edges of a glass with salt for flavor”. You can better learn the action(s) this word refers to with [this tutorial](http://mixthatdrink.com/how-to-rim-a-glass/).

In the [Google definition](https://www.google.com/search?num=100&q=rim&tbs=dfn:1&tbo=u&sa=X&ei=ktYTUv7AL9TyyAH7s4DAAQ&ved=0CCsQkQ4&biw=1680&bih=935), this usage is actually closest to the second verb meaning, even though it may seem more similar to the examples given for the first:

> 1. Form or act as an outer edge or rim for
>
>    - *a huge lake rimmed by glaciers*
>    - *steel-rimmed glasses*
> 2. **Mark with an encircling** stain or **deposit**
>
>    - *his collar was rimmed with dirt*

As you'll see in the tutorial linked above, the verb can often be used with no mention of the material being used because it's so commonly done with salt. Thus, if the context were already sufficiently specific, it might be fine to write is as:

> The drink is served in a rimmed glass.

Or, because the practice on the whole is fairly common (and with a nod to Peter Shor's comment below):

> The drink is served in a salted glass.

These other possibilities are less favorable because they are more ambiguous. As you may have already noted if you clicked through to the full Google definition, this a verb with which you will probably want to be a little more careful and restrictive with regard to context, lest it suggest the indecent.

Comment: +1: Actually, I suspect most bartenders just say "salted glass". "Salted glass" gets nearly 400 hits in Google, most of which seem to describe what the OP is looking for, while "salt-rimmed glass" only gets around 100. "Salted rim glass" gets two, and "rimmed salt glass" comes up with none, excluding this question. But if you want to emphasize that just the rim is salted and not the whole glass (probably unnecessary in most situations), "salt-rimmed" is the term you should use.

Comment: @PeterShor I’ve never heard “salted glass”, but I'm not a bartender. This wouldn't be the first time that Google hit-counts were inconsistent with my experience of a phrase’s commonness, though. I'll admit I didn't do any such comparisons, but my intent was to provide the term I imagined would serve the OP best in the broadest set of situations (which might not necessarily be the phrase used the most number of times among people writing about it on the Internet (even if we agree that’s what those numbers show)).

Comment: and you're right ... "salt-rimmed glass" is certainly much clearer than "salted glass" for most people, and equally clear even if you're a bartender.

Comment: @PeterShor Just to clarify my doubt about the numbers, even though we’re not at odds about the conclusion: The words “salted glass” have the unfair advantage of contributing to hit-[estimate]s whether they appear on their own, in the middle of phrases like “[such-and-such drink] with a _salted glass_ rim”, or describe unrelated things like [bath candles](http://ow.ly/o6Sgb) or any one of [these songs](http://ow.ly/o6SjZ), whereas “salt-rimmed glass” refers to this exact thing only, has very limited flexibility within normal sentence constructions, and would likely be used only once per page.

Comment: I guess I can see how mentions in music might be a good example of common use in some cases, but it still seems unfair to include them, since there are so many sites about music, and many of them are only making a simple directory-style reference to a song or band name with those words in it.